# JQuery processing strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working with jquery and i need to process strings. To be clear, it is a game with words where i take the word from database, than i choose a random number between 0 and the length of the word. Next, the chosen number will serve as a position for the letter of the word that will be hidden. So till here everything is ok. After making the word appear, and in the position where the letter should be, is a textbox, i wanna test 5 words. So when i test the first and the second, it works fine and then, the third word and other word till the end, they take the position of the previous word, not what they should take. I am providing the code below. Thank you!!!

```
            $(".next").click(function(){
            k = k + 2;

            if (k<10) {
                $(".next").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $(".result").html('');
                $(".check").removeClass("btn-success btn-danger disabled");
                $(".check").addClass("btn-default");
                $(".check").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');

                var nextWort = hiddenWord(res[k+1]);

                var rstring = nextWort.split("|");
                alert(rstring[1]);
                var poz2 = parseInt(rstring[1]);

                $(".bild").html(res[k]+"<br/>"+rstring[0]);

                $(".kot").html(k);

                $(".check").click(function(){

                    // var input = $(".wort-form").val();

                    if ($(".wort-form").val() == res[k+1][poz2]) {

                        $(".check").removeClass("btn-default");
                        $(".check").addClass("btn-success disabled");
                        $(".next").css("visibility", "visible");
                    }else{

                        $(".check").removeClass("btn-default");
                        $(".check").addClass("btn-danger disabled");
                        $(".check").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
                        $(".result").html("The missing letter is: <b>"+res[k+1][poz2]+"</b><br/>");
                        $(".next").css("visibility", "visible");

                    }



                });

            }else{
                window.location = "../flashcard/indexFlashcard.php";
            }


        });
```

so when button with class next is clicked, the next word appears, and when the button with class checked is clicked, it will check the word if the input letter is the correct one

hiddenWord function too

```
function hiddenWord(a){


var poz1 =Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);


var str = "";

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (i != poz1) {

        str += a[i];
    }else if(i == poz1){

        str +='<input type="text" id="latterone" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}" maxlength="1" class="form-control wort-form" style="width: 20px; text-align:center; display:inline; padding: 0;">';
    }
}

return str+"|"+poz1;
```

}

Comment: Please post the HTML and the full JS code (if it is partial). (use the "edit" link below your question)

Comment: There is not much HTML. Basically all HTML of this part, and js too is given. What I wanna mention is that I take a large string from php file using ajax, and split it based in | character. So that the first part is path of the image and the second the word describing the image. The image and the word are stored in db

Comment: Well... I just can't recreate the problem easily using just what is posted. So maybe a live link would be easy for you to share. You mentionned Ajax... This is asynchronous, so maybe the problem source is there. I just can't tell for now.

Comment: Well I can't provide a link since it is in localhost. It seams that when check I clicked for a second time, it wont call the hiddenWord function properly

Comment: If you don't help me hepl you... I can't do much. Just find a way to share the whole thing. Your localhost certainly has an ip address...